Symfony EasyAdmin, how to add a list of elements coming from the database storing it as a collection
We are building an application in which the application can have configuration per entity. Specifically we have a Domain entity with a collection of CssSelector entities.
The available css selectors to configure are setup in another Entity called AvailableCssSelectors.
Now we want to add ALL the available css selectors to an admin panel of a domain, so the user is able to configure the available css selectors for a domain.
So basically the database of CssSelector entity contains a relation to one Domain and one AvailableCssSelectors. With a text field to configure the css selector.
The only thing that should be a text field is the "css selector" field that's stored as css selector.
I'm not sure how to add this in Symfony EasyAdmin from the Domain view, since it's not really a Collection, it's also not an ArrayEntity, it's also not an Association.
